# Differential amplifier with two opamps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, transfer-function

Recently, I was asked in a final exam how to do this. I tried to apply superposition but I think I am not understanding something in here.

[image: circuit]

Does anyone know how to calculate the transfer function of this configuration? The question is to obtain the output at the exit of U1.

Comment: Where is the output? The junction of R4 and R5?

Comment: Go research instumentation amplifiers and ditto the above comment.

Comment: Pretty sure you have drawn that wrong, R5 should probably connect between the output and inverting input of U1 in the same manner as R4 does for U2.

Answer (score 1):

I assume Op Amps are ideal in the question. Write a KCL at the inverting input of U1 to find the output of U2 in terms of V1 and V2. Then write another KCL at the inverting input of U2. The latter will let you find an expression for the output of U1 as a function of V1 and V2. Note that due to the infinite open loop gain of the Op Amps the inverting and non-inverting inputs of each Op Amp are equal. Hope it helps.